# Not able to proceed with Series sum

Tags: java

I wanted to find the missing number in series so i thought a simple idea why not add all the numbers in array which are in series and hold it in one variable and then calculate the sum of series by formula `Sn=n/2(a+l)` but while calculating the series sum i am getting some error.

```
public class Missing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    int ar [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
    int sum = 0; int total=0;
    for(int num: ar)
    {
        sum = sum+num;
    }



        int n = ar.length;
        int a = ar[0];
        int l =ar[ar.length-1];
         total = [n/2*(a+l)];

         System.out.print("The missing number is "+(sum-total));

}}
```

> total = [n/2*(a+l)];     ............................(1)

This is where i am getting error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PTqN.png)

Comment: not able to accomplish the solution yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is in `total = [n/2*(a+l)];` `[]` is not valid syntax in this context. The second thing I noticed, is that your formula to calculate the sum seems odd, maybe you meant `Sn = (n * (a + l)) / 2?`. After making those two changes the code should look as follows:

```
public class Missing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int ar [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
        int sum = 0; 
        for(int num: ar)
        {
            sum = sum+num;
        }

        int n = ar.length;
        int a = ar[0];
        int l =ar[ar.length - 1];
        int total = (n * (a + l)) / 2;
        System.out.print("The missing number is "+(sum - total));
        // outputs 0 which is correct nothing is missing

        // Now if you remove say 12 from the array
        // by changing the array to int ar [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,0,13};
        // you should get back -12 which means 12 is missing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below logic which is much simpler to use and understand

```
for(int i=0;i<ar.length-1;i++)
{
        if(ar[i]!=ar[i+1]-1)
        {   
            System.out.print("The missing number is "+(ar[i]+1)+"\n");
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use my above logic. You have to make changes to your code:
Edit this:

```
int n = ar.length+1;
```

n has been assigned ar.length + 1 because that +1 is needed to compensate for the missing element in the array list

Also, the formula has not been correctly written into the code:

```
total = (n* (a + l))/2;
```

If you first divide n by 2 then, it will truncate the places after decimal point because n is an integer not a floating number. So, your logic would fail when n is not even.

And lastly, the missing number would be (sum-total) not the other way around because 'total' contains the missing number and 'sum' does not.

```
System.out.print("The missing number is "+(total-sum));
```